# How to route some email accounts of a domain with transport_maps to another MX if user doesn't exist locally?

Tags: postfix

The MX server in my domain **example.com** point to my Postfix server.
However, I have also configured a Google Apps account responsible for emails of **example.com**.

I want all emails to go to my Postfix server (this is already done by the MX setting in the DNS zone), but want some users of this domain to be forwarded to the MX **aspmx.l.google.com**.

I did this with the transport_maps parameter. Here is the file **/etc/postfix/transport**.

> test@example.com  smtp:[aspmx.l.google.com]

The problem is, **smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient** is set to **yes** by default, but postfix checks existence of user before applying the transport map. My Postfix server doesn't know the user **test** for this domain, so it simply rejects the email.

I would like to make transport routing happen before recipient existence check (in my current setting, only Google SMTP is aware of existence of user **test**). Is that possible?

Note: local_recipient_maps doesn't work for me because  I use the virtual transport with dovecot. So the recipient table is virtual_mailbox_maps.

Comment: can you post the output of `postconf -n` to help you better.

Comment: try to use "local_recipient_maps ="

Comment: In my case, I use the virtual transport with dovecot. So the table is virtual_mailbox_maps. But I don't like it conceptually that I have to add an entry in the transport maps and in the virtual_mailbox_maps to route the traffic outside. It makes information redundant.
Why doesn't the routing happen before the recipient existence check? Isn't there is way? When I route emails, I mean "The current Postfix doesn't handle anything and just forwards email to another server which is fully responsible for the config".

Answer (score 1):

> Why doesn't the routing happen before the recipient existence check? Isn't there is way? When I route emails, I mean "The current Postfix doesn't handle anything and just forwards email to another server which is fully responsible for the config".

No, that isn't way postfix gonna works. Recipient existence checks and email routing was two different activities for postfix. Recipient existence checks was performed when **accepting email**. The process who performs it was [smtpd](http://www.postfix.org/smtpd.8.html). Email routing  was performed when **delivering email**. The process who perform it was [trivial-rewrite](http://www.postfix.org/trivial-rewrite.8.html)

---

In the comment, you mention that you use [virtual delivery agent from postfix](http://www.postfix.org/virtual.8.html) to delivering email. I'm gonna tell you that it possible to achieve no-redundant-information in postfix configuration. BUT you must change current postfix setup.

To achieve your goal, we must move all domains in `virtual_mailbox_domain` class to `relay_domains` class. Then using dovecot LDA to deliver email in the right mailbox. Relay domains class has special parameter called relay_recipient_maps to checks the recipient existence.

The good news is you can use `relay_recipient_maps` together with `transport_maps`. Why? Because relay_recipient_maps only used to **check existence** of user. The value/right hand side string in transport_maps was ignored when recipient existence check. Snippet from [man postconf](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html).

> Optional lookup tables with all valid addresses in the domains that match $relay_domains. Specify @domain as a wild-card for domains that have no valid recipient list, and become a source of backscatter mail: Postfix accepts spam for non-existent recipients and then floods innocent people with undeliverable mail. Technically, tables listed with $relay_recipient_maps are used as lists: Postfix needs to know only if a lookup string is found or not, but it does not use the result from table lookup.

---

For the completeness, here the postfix configuration for this setup. Credits to [sebokopter](https://serverfault.com/users/78147/sebokopter) for [the idea](https://serverfault.com/a/640621/218590).

```
#main.cf
# rename virtual_mailbox_domains to relay_domains
relay_domains = mydomain.example.com
# put the parameter value of virtual_mailbox_maps AND transport_maps parameter
relay_recipient_maps = hash:/my/virtual_mailbox_maps, hash:/my/transport_maps

transport_maps = hash:/my/transport_maps
relay_transport = dovecot:

#master.cf
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
    flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/local/libexec/dovecot/dovecot-lda -f ${sender} -d ${recipient}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue, to fix I just created the virtual users in my database and it allowed postfix to complete the recipient existence check and get to rerouting to a different MX Server.

I know its a bit of a hack, personally it works for me as the accounts that are being rerouted will eventually be relocated to the same MX and so the user accounts are valid.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by doing a similar thing as mailman3:

1. Create an alias subdomain (e.g. gm.example.com) in gmail. Please note, that for some weird reason gmail.example.com is not allowed by gmail.
2. Add this subdomain to relay_domains (I used a hash map)
3. Use virtual_alias_maps to forward your main domain to your new subdomain for the gmail users
4. Add your gmail users to the transport_maps using this subdomain

virtual_alias_map:

```
test@example.com test@gm.example.com
```

transport_map:

```
test@gm.example.com smtp:aspmx.l.google.com
```