# Migration Issue from Postfix

Tags: postfix, google

I am currently using postfix, recently I have started to migrate the mailbox to Google App for Work. 
While I changed the MX record from provider, it should be great that all outcoming emails to my domain, has been diverted to the google mail service, BUT the email send internally (Some users using another domain) is delivered to the mailbox in postfix.

May I know any solution to divert those email to Google App for Work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For temporary solution, you can setup transport_maps and list all of **migrated domains** in there. For example

```
# main.cf
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/gapps, other/transport/maps

# /etc/postfix/gapps
example.com smtp:example.com
example.org smtp:example.org
```

The point of using `tranport_maps` is you **force** the email next-hop. Instead delivering it to local mailbox, you force postfix to deliver it based on MX record of your GApps domain. So, it would override the routing rule in postfix.

---

For permanent solution you need remove the **migrated domains** from `mydestination`, `virtual_alias_domains`, `virtual_mailbox_domains` parameter and put it in `relay_domains` paremeter.

```
relay_domains = example.com example.org
```

References:

- [Postfix Address Classes Readme](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_CLASS_README.html)
- [This tutorial by  Scott Hebert](http://slaptijack.com/system-administration/redirecting-user-email-to-google-with-postfix/)
- [This postfix question of SF](https://serverfault.com/questions/592908/how-to-route-some-email-accounts-of-a-domain-with-transport-maps-to-another-mx-i)

Comment: Thanks. For temp. solution, Is that I should excluded the domain (hosted in Google) from the domain list in transport_maps, right?

Comment: See, the updated answer above. You need list all GApps domain to transport_maps

Comment: If this answer your problem, consider to [accept it](http://serverfault.com/help/someone-answers). It's the Server Fault way of saying thank you :)

Comment: Hi, I found that there is a statement for transport_map 
"transport_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-transport.cf"
May I have the advise? thanks

Comment: Put gapps before mysql. `transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/gapps, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-transport.cf`

Comment: Masegaloeh, Thank you for your help.
I have tried your solution provided but no luck, I cannot send the email from by IMAP client (Mail app in MAC), and outcoming email cannot be delivered to my server.

Comment: Actually my solution above was very general as I don't know your existing configuration. Maybe You  need to modify it so it won't break your system